# How to relate tables that share some shared values

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am trying to come up with a good solution for the following scenario.

Let's say I have a table named **Movies** which contains the following columns.

- ID
- Title
- Category
- Released Countries

Then I have another table named **Category** which contains the following columns.

- ID
- Name

The categories would be Horror, Thriller and Animation

Lastly I have a table named **Countries** which contains the countries

- ID
- Name

The countries list would be Canada, USA, Mexico and Brazil.

What should I do if I want to have a movie with several Categories and Countries but not all of them for each movie??

For instance:

- Movie 1 is horror and thriller. It is released in the US, Canada and
  Mexico
- Movie 2 is animation. It is released in Mexico and Brazil.

What would be the way I should relate these three tables? Is there any other table I should add here?

Comment: Your current database schema is not normalized.  The category and country tables should have a movie ID, which they currently don't.

Comment: In that case I will have repeated categories and countries on the Category and Countries trables for each of the movies that relate each Category and Country respectively, right?

Comment: For example, the category table should have two columns, one for movie ID, the other for category ID.  In other words, a single movie could have multiple records in the category table.  Do the same for countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add tables:

- Movie_Category (Movie_ID, Category_ID)
- Movie_Countries (Movie_ID, Country_ID)

Comment: What would be the relation between these two tables and the Category and Country tables?

Comment: 1:n between movie and category, 1:n between movie and country

Comment: 1:n relationships do _not_ need extra tables.  All you need is an extra column.  For example, if a Movie is filmed in exactly one Country, add a 2-letter `country_code` to the `Movies` table.  If you want to list all the countries involved in a Movie (many:many mapping), you _do_ need an extra table.